# @Query - Returning primitive type or String object?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm facing a little problem trying to retrieve an int value or String looking for Top record or last record on my DB, depending in what I want.
Looking in Spring data documentation I found something like this:

```
Vaccine findTopByOrderByVaccineCodeDesc();
```

Which is perfectly well but is returning a Vaccine, I don't want the whole Vaccine Object, I just want for example the "vaccine code". I tried something like this:

```
String findTop1ByOrderByVaccineCodeDesc();
```

But unfortunately is wrong! It's not working. But what about this:

```
@Query("SELECT TOP v.vaccineCode FROM Vaccine v ORDER BY vaccineCode Desc")
String getLastRecordByVaccineCode();
```

I know this is syntactically wrong wrote because I'm using TOP in wrong way but I don't know how to do it.
Any advice? I really appreciate a clue how to find the answer in the documentation or how to read the doc cauze I'm no good looking in the doc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EntityManager

```
public String getVaccineCode {
@AutoWired
EntityManager entityManager;
String vaccineCode = (String) entityManager.createQuery("SELECT v.vaccineCode FROM Vaccine v ORDER BY vaccineCode Desc", String.class).getFirstResult());
return vaccineCode;
}
```